# Force-call a specific constructor in a parent's class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, overloading

I'm facing for the first time the following case:

I have the [following java class](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/tuple/Values.html):

```java
public class Values extends ArrayList<Object>{
    public Values() {

    }

    public Values(Object... vals) {
        super(vals.length);
        for(Object o: vals) {
            add(o);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to call the [following parent's constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29):

```java
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```

Is this possible ? I'm sending an `int` but it's caught by the Values's constructor.

**Edit**

What i'd like to do in the end is :

```
Map<String,Object> document = getDocument();
List<String> indexFields = getIndexFields();
Values values = new Values(indexFields.size());
for (String field : indexFields) {
    values.add(document.get(field));
}
```

Comment: where is the problem? `super(vals.length);` should invoke the constructor you want

Comment: @Crystark something is not ok here. Calling super(vals.length) calls the ArrayList, initialCapacity constructor. How do you know that the conscturctor is not getting called?

Comment: Advice: It is often better to implements List<Object>, decalre an internal ArrayList and delegate method call (add, addAll..etc) to the ArrayList methods.

Comment: @MarcoForberg i've edited my post with what i want to do. It should be self-explanatory. As you can see, i myself am looping so i didn't want to do it twice.

Comment: @Eugene It's not a problem of getting called. My problem is that i don't want the "Object constructor" to be called but the "int constructor"

Comment: @Cygnusx1 Yep, but i don't have my hands on the Values's code. I'm just using it through a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call `new Values(initialCapacity)` where `initialCapacity` is an `int`, then you should have such a constructor in the `Values` class:

```
public Values(int initialCapacity) {
    super(initialCapacity);
}
```

Note that it's generally not a good idea to extend collection classes. Use them (delegation, composition) instead of extending them.

Comment: That's what i thought. Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: hmmm if you already thought this, why didn't you just try it?